# Is it a good practice to store num_of_x column in SQL Tables?

Tags: sql, database

**Let's consider an example:**

A database designed to store department information in a company:

- The HR department has five employees.
- There's two table: Department and Employees

It is a frequent use case that you wish to find out how many employees does department x have. There are two ways to get number of employees, one is keeping it in a column, the other is looking up the count in the employee table

**My question is this:**

**Does it make sense to store a `num_of_employees` column in Department table?**

Here's what my views are:

- It'll be a bit of a headache to always keep the count value in the `num_of_` columns synced to the actual number in the other table (requiring triggers on insertion, deletion)
- In the case where only the number of employees is actually required: The query will be significantly faster (as it won't have to do a `count(*)` on the other table at all)

Now, the above was a rather simplified version of the real problem I have which is dozens of inter-connected table, with frequent querying use cases where I am asking, wherever X = (some value) in table 1, how many corresponding rows (via foreign key) does it have in table 2, table 3 and so on.

So, when is it a good practice to have `num_of_x` columns in a table? Does the above use-case count as a good situation where it should be used (or not)?

Comment: This is entirely situation/opinion based... in my opinion you should never do this unless you can quantify the benefits and that these benefits show a decent performance gain. SQL Server, with the right indexes can count rows very fast. With all things SQL Server, my advice, do it correctly in the first instance and only make exceptions to solve a specific performance problem after it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The number of employees in a department can easily be calculated using:

```
select count(*)
from employees e
where e.department_id = ?;
```

With an index on `department_id`, this should be pretty fast and always up-to-date.

Maintaining a count on a central table is faster for querying purposes.  However, it requires having triggers for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s on the `employees table -- triggers that slow down DML operations.

Under most circumstances, just use a query to calculate the value.  If performance is an issue, consider more extreme solutions such as pre-calculating the value.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to store a num_of_employees column in Department table?

That's *redundancy*. Redundancy can have:

- Benefits: Redundancy can be helpful when it's expensive to compute the value each time. This way you just get the value without any further delay.
- Drawbacks: Redundancy keeps the same value repeated multiple times in the database. This could lead to discrepancies, or some values to be stale.

In your particular case I would think there benefits would be small (cheap to compute the value) with significant drawbacks (showing stale/wrong value). Considering this I would [personally] not use redundancy for this case.